# Android Push Notification Self Development

Tags: java, php, android, google-cloud-messaging

My (maybe silly) question is: **Is it manageable to develop a little version of Google Cloud Messaging on my own?**

I would really like to understand how this all works in detail, but especially for some android applications.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a little version of Google Cloud Messaging"?

Comment: Not all function that GCM provides, just the basic (sending, receiving)

Comment: yes, you need to use socket programming :-) but be user friendly and use the one that all developers use so it saves the battery better.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation!